# Build Error TFS 2015 "No appropriate mapping exists for..." to codes outside mapping

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

Was recently implemented in the company to function Gated Check-in through build. Since there were already several codes in the company, only a few were mapped to be built by the build; in a recent check-in, a programmer included at the same check-in a code that is outside of the build mapping and this caused the build to fail. Is there any way around this problem?

Further details:

Suppose the repository has solutions A, B, C, D and E

In Triggers>Gated Check-in, projects A, B and C are included. (Nothing excludes)

In Repository>Mappings, projects A, B and C are included (Nothing Cloak)

When performing a check-in that includes projects B and D, the build fails with the message

> "No appropriate mapping exists for $/{Repository}/D..."

Since D is not part of the triggers or build mapping, there would be no need to receive the codes in the first place.

Is there anything that can be done since there is no intention of including D and E in the build?

Answer (score 1):

The developer will need to perform multiple check-ins: One (or more) for the stuff that isn't part of the gated check-in, one (or more) for the stuff that is.